# cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table

Tags: oracle11g

Currently, I want to delete this user's items from different cart tables. So I came up with it.

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT *
FROM EXH_CART EC, PRODUCT_CART PC, MEMBER M
WHERE PC.USER_NUM(+) = M.USER_NUM
AND EC.USER_NUM(+) = M.USER_NUM
AND M.USER_NUM = 6);
```

But this code gave me that error.

```
SQL error: ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table
01752. 00000 - "cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table"
*Cause: The deleted table had
           - no key-preserved tables;
           - more than one key-preserved table, or
           - the key-preserved table was an unmerged view.
*Action: Redefine the view or delete it from the underlying base tables.
```

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hyqd.png)

How can I fix this error?? Please help.

Comment: You must delete from each table individually. Ideally you would have `on delete cascade` constraints on the foreign keys of the child tables that would delete from those tables automatically when you delete the parent record.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.Is there any other way other than that??

Comment: You cannot combine different tables in the same delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation of the DELETE command (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505), the syntax does not support multiple tables, joins, or other similar constructs. You must issue separate delete commands for each related table:

```
DELETE FROM MEMBER M WHERE M.USER_NUM = 6;
DELETE FROM EXH_CART EC WHERE EC.USER_NUM = 6;
DELETE FROM PRODUCT_CART PC WHERE PC.USER_NUM = 6;
COMMIT;
```

As I mentioned in the comments, ideally you would have a formal foreign key relationship between the child and parent tables, with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option set so that you would then only have to delete the record from the parent table and let the database handle the child records automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. So I try to process it as a transaction.

Comment: If you have foreign keys defined _without_ `on delete cascade` option, then you will have to delete all of the child table records first before deleting the parent record. If there are _no_ foreign keys defined then you can delete the parent or child records from any table in any order.