# Delete on Oracle DB when joining with a piplined table function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called CUSTOMERS from which I want to delete all entries that are not present in VALUE_CUSTOMERS. VALUE_CUSTOMERS is a Pipelined Table Function which builds on customers.

```
DELETE
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM CUSTOMERS
  LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 
        1 AS DELETABLE, 
        VC.* 
      FROM 
        (
          CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30)) VC
        )
    USING
      (
        FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH
      )
  WHERE 
    DELETABLE IS NULL  
)
;
```

When I try to execute the statement, I get the Error:

> ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved
> table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734904/cannot-delete-from-view-without-exactly-one-key-preserved-table#:~:text=SQL%20error%3A%20ORA%2D01752%3A,table%20was%20an%20unmerged%20view.

Comment: Have you tried:

DELETE FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30) vc
 WHERE 
  vc.first_name = c.first_name 
  AND vc.last_name = c.last_name 
  AND vc.date_of_birth = c.date_of_birth
);

Comment: I just tried it. Unfortunatelly I now get **ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're example has wrong syntax (lack of `table` keyword) - I've tested it on Oracle 12c, so maybe it works on newer ones. Below some ideas - based on Oracle 12c.

You've got multiple options here:

1. **Save result of `CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS` to some temporary table and use it in your query**

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_CUSTOMERS (
  FIRST_NAME <type based on CUSTOMERS.FIRST_NAME>
  , LAST_NAME <type based on CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME>
  , DATE_OF_BIRTH <type based on CUSTOMERS.DATE_OF_BIRTH>
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Then in code:

```
INSERT INTO TMP_CUSTOMERS(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH)
  SELECT VC.FIRST_NAME, VC.LAST_NAME, VC.DATE_OF_BIRTH
    FROM TABLE(CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30)) VC
;

-- and then:
DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS C
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
    FROM TMP_CUSTOMERS TMP_C
    -- Be AWARE that NULLs are not handled here 
    -- so it's correct only if FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH are not nullable
    WHERE C.FIRST_NAME = TMP_C.FIRST_NAME
      AND C.LAST_NAME = TMP_C.LAST_NAME
      AND C.DATE_OF_BIRTH = TMP_C.DATE_OF_BIRTH
  )
;

-- If `CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS` can return a lot of rows,
-- then you should create indexes on FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH
-- or maybe even 1 multi-column index on all of above columns.
```

Also, consider rewriting your query. You should insert into `TMP_CUSTOMERS` just a customer ID and then call a delete based on these ids.

The main risk here is that the data could be changed between these 2 operations and you should consider that issue.

2. **You can save result in collection variable and then do a `bulk delete` with `forall loop`.**
   If number of rows to delete could be big, then you should extend this example using `LIMIT` clause. Even with limit, you still could encounter some problems - like not enough space in `UNDO`. So this solution is good only for small amount of data. The risk here is the same as in example above.

```
DECALRE
  type t_tab is table of number index by pls_integer;
  v_tab t_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT CUSTOMER.ID -- I hope you have some kind of Primary key there...
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_tab
  FROM CUSTOMERS
  LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 
        1 AS DELETABLE, 
        VC.* 
      FROM TABLE(CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30)) VC
    )
    USING
      (
        FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH
      )
  WHERE 
    DELETABLE IS NULL  
  ;

  FORALL idx in 1..V_TAB.COUNT()
    DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS
      WHERE CUSTOMERS.ID = V_TAB(idx)
  ;
END;
/
```

3. **Do it completely different - that's preferable.**

   For example: logic from `CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS` move to a `view` and based on that `view` create a `delete statement`. Remember to change `CUSTOMER_PACKAGE.VALUE_CUSTOMERS` to use that new view also (DRY principle).